# Can I Add Error Handling To An Existing Partial Class?

Tags: c#, error-handling

I have an existing partial class that has no error handling (any errors are simply thrown to the consuming code).

In the example below, I would like to add error management to `MyClass` to provide better information to the consuming class. (I have already added a `Helper` partial class to `MyClass` for other reasons).

What I can't work how to do - if it's possible - is how to extend the partial class with error management (trapping, conversion to a class error property, etc).

Example:

```
partial class MyClass
{
    static void MyMethod()
    {
        throw new Exception("An error from MyClass.MyMethod");
    }

    void MyTest()
    {
        MyMethod();
    }
}
```

Here, when `MyTest.MyMethod()` is called, an unhandled exception is thrown.

Ideally, I would be able to add a partial extension to `MyClass` which traps and manages such errors within the class. Obviously, I could wrap the class and manage the errors there, and perhaps that's the best/only way to do it, but I'd like opinions.

NOTE: Let's assume I have no control over `MyClass` tho in reality, in this instance, it's code generated by `Swagger CodeGen`, so I kinda do, but I'd rather not break into code generation any more than I already have.

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand the premise of the question. If you're adding a partial class, can't you just add whatever you want to it? What have you tried? What's not working vs your expectations?

Comment: @gilliduck Yes, sure I can add to the class, but I can't, say, intercept the throwing of an exception from a method within the original (partial) class (that I know of). And, yes, of course I've had a go and searched the web and SO; I'm here asking because I haven't arrived at a solution.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand, you are asking if you can manipulate method invocations/control flow by adding something in a second partial class fie without any modification to the first file.  As far as I am aware -- You cannot manipulate existing methods or the control flow from a partial class.  Partial classes only allow you to split the definition into multiple files.  I believe the only way to add error handling, without modifying the original methods, is to adapt or wrap (or inherit if they happen to be virtual).

Comment: Thanks. Your reading of the question is correct. That's what I expected, but I wanted input from better C# coders than I. I've since read about some third-party class wrappers which can provide class error handling but I don't want to add in a TP reference.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solutions will be inheritance from and\or writing wrapper of your class.

Other methods may be little crazy, like

https://doc.postsharp.net/method-decorator

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16359/%2FArticles%2F16359%2FMethodLogger-Hook-into-method-calls-in-NET-binarie

However also it may be better just to handle exceptions in consuming code.

Comment: Seems there should be a better solution than a wrapper/decorator, but thanks for the suggestion!  I may have to try that.
Unfortunately, it isn't viable to ("handle exceptions in consuming code") because methods in *partial* classes don't pass exceptions up to the caller the same way that methods in a regular class (in a single .cs file) does, which seems like a design flaw.